# How to add attribute if new letter is introduced?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this very simple XML:

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <name>Allan</name>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Ben</name>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Brad</name>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Charles</name>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>David</name>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

I also have this XSL that loops over all the entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="entries">
      <xsl:for-each select="entry">
          <span>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </span>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a simple way to add a css class to each entry that starts with a new letter?

In the example above all entries except the one with *Brad* would get such a class.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this *could* be perceived as a grouping problem, you could also look at it as simply as stated. This is assuming the entries are already sorted in the order you wanted them.

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <span>
        <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(preceding-sibling::entry[1]/name, substring(name, 1 ,1)))">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">foo</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

To make this non case-sensitive, try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <span>
        <xsl:if test="translate(substring(name, 1 ,1), $upper-case, $lower-case) != translate(substring(preceding-sibling::entry[1]/name, 1 ,1), $upper-case, $lower-case)">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">foo</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

after defining:

```
<xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
```

Comment: In fact, this solution works best for me, since my entries are coming out of the database already sorted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is a grouping problem, see http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYit, it uses [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="group" match="entry" use="substring(name, 1, 1)"/>

<xsl:template match="entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', substring(name, 1, 1))[1])]">
    <span class="foo">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', substring(name, 1, 1))[1]))]">
    <span>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you want to compare case-insensitive then you need to use `translate`:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="group" match="entry" use="translate(substring(name, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>

<xsl:template match="entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', translate(substring(name, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]">
    <span class="foo">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', translate(substring(name, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1]))]">
    <span>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! The only thing that bothers me is that it is case sensitive, i.e. it also adds a class *foo* to a *Brad* if its predecessor is a *ben*. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You can use the `translate` function in XPath 1.0 to convert letters, it gets a bit ugly as you have to spell out the letters you want to convert but it is doable, define global variables or parameters `<xsl:variable name="uc" select="'ABC...Z'"/> (you need to spell that out), `<xsl:variable name="lc" select="'abc...z'"/>`, then set up the key as `<xsl:key name="group" match="entry" use="translate(substring(name, 1, 1), $uc, $lc)"/>` and of course use the same in the expressions checking the key. Hmm, that is the theory, unfortunately XSLT 1.0 does not allow variables in patterns. Need to edit

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0:

```
  <xsl:template match="entries">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" 
                          group-by="substring(name, 1, 1)">          
          <span class="new-letter>
              <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
          </span>
          <span class="same-letter>
              <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
          </span>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get this to work, so I assume I must be using XSLT 1.0.